# springdoc-openapi-ui '1.6.11' dependency conflict

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have the conflict and it looks like internal conflict for the springdoc dependencies, how can I solve it:

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.36
\--- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:0.50
     \--- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.11
          \--- compileClasspath

org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.35 -> 1.7.36
\--- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:2.2.2
     \--- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:1.6.11
          \--- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:1.6.11
               \--- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.11
                    \--- compileClasspath
```

Comment: Yes, I can force it to 1.7.36, but it looks like a bug.

Comment: Mind highlighting the conflicting classpath?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Sorry, I'm not sure that I've clearly understood you :(

Comment: Which JAR(s) are leading to the conflict? Can you share the dependencies you have in your POM file?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy we are using Gradle, so I've added the import only: 
`implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.11'`
And `dependencyInsight` command showed me the trees listed above.